# Keeping ssh connections open on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh

I know that on Unix Systems, you can keep an ssh connection open.

Step 1: Create a ssh configuration, for example:

```
 Host <some.host.name>
 ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
 ControlPersist yes
```

Step 2: Start ssh with the `-M` parameter.

**Is there something equivalent under Windows to reuse ssh connections?** Maybe I looked at the wrong places, but I didn't find any good links on this topic.

(I tried my approach from above in a MingGW environment (using MingGW's ssh client). In real Unix system, it should have created a special socket file in `~/.ssh`, but that functionality does not seem to be supported by MingGW.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use openssh for windows, either through cygwin, or this port: http://miked.ict.rave.ac.uk/display/sshwindows/OpenSSH+for+Windows

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be a good starting point. OpenSSH for Windows seems to support connection sharing.

Comment: Is this really a correct answer? OpenSSH for Windows works on top of a cygwin — either full cygwin or a minimal cygwin implementation like that linked here. In either case, I understand that ControlPersist does not work because it requires passing file descriptors over sockets, which is not supported in cygwin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959792/is-ssh-controlmaster-with-cygwin-on-windows-actually-possible

Comment: I couldn't get keepalive to work, but I fixed it by downgrading ssh from 8.0 to 7.9 so watch out for that

Comment: @dk. It is likely a reasonable answer, but does omit a key constraint in that it does not work for connections that need a pseudo-terminal.  In other words, I found openssh  in MSYS2 to support use of ControlMaster/ControlPersist only for non-interactive connections.  If I tried to open a terminal, I got the errors like:
mm_send_fd: sendmsg(2): Broken pipe
mux_client_request_session: send fds failed

See also: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1278

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about two different things:

Your subject indicates keeping connections open indefinitely, where my answer would be:
  If you are using puTTY, then you can set a keepalive in the configuration of a session:
  Configuration => Connection:
    Sending of null packets to keep session active
    Seconds between keepalives (0 to turn off)

Your text indicates connection sharing. No idea for puTTY with that.

Kind regards,
Viktor Zacek

Comment: Yes, you are right. I actually meant connection sharing.

Answer (score 1):

[Bug 1278 - CYGWIN controlMaster connections don't work.](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1278) describes use of ControlMaster/ControlPersist as partially implemented under Cygwin as of December, 2016, but with a qualification that it works only for remote commands and not for connections that require a pseudo terminal.

While this answer was not confirmed under Cygwin, per se, it was validated as true for MSYS2 (based on Cygwin).  openssh under MSYS2 supports ControlMaster/ControlPersist connections for remote commands, but not for interactive sessions.

```
$ cygcheck -V | head -3
cygcheck (msys) 3.0.7
System Checker for Msys
Copyright (C) 1998 - 2019 Cygwin Authors

$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019

$ pacman -Qi openssh
Name            : openssh
Version         : 8.1p1-1
Description     : Free version of the SSH connectivity tools
Architecture    : i686
URL             : https://www.openssh.com/portable.html
Licenses        : custom:BSD
Groups          : net-utils
Provides        : None
Depends On      : heimdal  libedit  libcrypt  openssl
Optional Deps   : None
Required By     : sshpass
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 4.55 MiB
Packager        : Alexey Pavlov <alexpux@gmail.com>
Build Date      : Mon, Oct 14, 2019 1:12:28 AM
Install Date    : Thu, Oct 24, 2019 8:38:48 PM
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
```

The following errors occur when running `ssh` without a remote command specified:

```
mm_send_fd: sendmsg(2): Broken pipe
mux_client_request_session: send fds failed
```

With remote commands specified, the errors do not occur.